# Android Navigation Bar being overridden when modal is present - React Native - Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have changed my Android Navigation Bar color to #2AA6BF to match my app's bottom nav bar. When a modal is present, the nav bar color gets overridden to white or black.

Originally, I changed the color in the App.js file. Then I switched to changing the nav bar color in the app.json file hoping that it would fix it. It did not. To test, I tried changing the nav bar color to #FF0000 directly in the modal's file. When the modal opens, you see the change to #FF0000 right before it's overridden to black (when the color is #2AA6BF it overrides to white).

Here is what I have currently
**app.json**
`"androidStatusBar": { "backgroundColor": "#2AA6BF" },`

**Modal.js**
`const result = NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("#FF0000");`
and the import statement:
`import * as NavigationBar from 'expo-navigation-bar';`

if it helps, this is how my modals are structured:
`<Modal visible={exampleModalVisible} animationType="slide" > <ExampleModal onClose={handleExampleTrendModal} /> </Modal>`